# Discord.js | When I attempt to run my Discord.js command, it will spit out an error "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner attempting to create a Discord bot, and I have gone through a few tutorials on how to do so. So far I have a few functional commands that just spit out text, but I wanted to try my hand at role management.
I made it so if you already had the role it would spit out "You don't have that" and I made it so if you did NOT have the role, it would grant it to you.

I think that my code is trying to read execute as a variable instead of a function.

Here is my source code;

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'general',
    description: "adds the role general to the user of the command",

    execute(message, args) {

        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('794005115648475198')){
            message.channel.send('You already have that role.');


        } else {
            message.channel.send('sending you their way, enjoy the ride!');
            message.member.roles.add('794005115648475198').catch(console.error)
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the main.js file as well. (With a few things blurred out)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix= '!a '

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Atlas online');
});

const fs = require('fs')

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('js'))
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'ea') {
        client.commands.get('ea').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'sports') {
        client.commands.get('sports').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'whoisagoodboy') {
        message.channel.send('i am!');
    } else if (command === 'rolegeneral') {
        client.commands.get('rolegeneral').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('-------------------------');
```

I'm not sure whether it is VSCode, or my dumb coding.

(P.S) Yes this is from a tutorial, yes I have double checked with that code and as you can see it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In your main.js file, you do

```
client.commands.get('rolegeneral')
```

however in your command the name is just 'general', maybe that's an issue?

If not, what error are you actually experiencing? Does anything log into console?